# Website looks awful on mobile devices

Tags: mobile

I'm a newbie and finally put online the page I've been working on for the past 3 weeks: www.alweso.2ap.pl

I'm aware of the fact that it still requires a lot of work to be done, that the code is messy and so on - this was my first project and I've been basically just trying things out and learning from it.

What I don't understand is why does the page look so messy on mobile phones - I've been using Mozilla Developer Tools, changing the viewport size etc. and it looked pretty decent - now checking it live it's a complete mess.

I will appreciate any help, a starting point from which to begin fixing this disaster.

---

Thnx for both answers, unfortunaltely it didn't help. I also see that the video is not showing up - should I add a different format or smth? I have mp4 and webm.

In general it looks like the mobile version is completely ignoring any media queries that I applied and that worked in Mozilla Developer Tools.

I have absolutely no idea what to do about this and I'm desperate for some help. It seemed good to the point that today I wanted to send some CV's for some junior positions, but they all require responsive web design - and I can't send them smth like that...

Comment: Show up your media queries, sounds like they are wrong.

Comment: @Damien Black - I think it's better if you see them in the context - check out the source code for the website and go to superparalax.css - they are all there. Hope you find the problem!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this line somewhere in the `head`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

Phones 'lie' about how large they are so that they can get a good looking page on sites that aren't designed for small screen sizes. If your page looks good on smaller sizes, you need to add the line above to get them to stop 'lying'.

Answer (score 1):

I think the site looks great but in order for it to look properly on mobile you should look into using a foundation such as bootstrap or zurb. getbootstrap.com or zurb.com

You can also add the viewport remember to include the scale!

```
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Somewhere on the way I decided that for the next website I will learn Bootstrap, as after some reading it seems to be a way more stable solution. This time I'm still hoping to make it work without it, not to change everything that I've done for the past 3 weeks.